# cloning / compiling with msys shell , some files appear "\#include "xyz.h"

Tags: c, windows, gstreamer, gnu-make

I am cloning/compiling some `gstreamer` repos within msys64 shell , for example :

`git clone git://anongit.freedesktop.org/git/gstreamer/gst-plugins-base && cd gst-plugins-base && git checkout 1.16.1`

After compiling with `make`, something strange happens to the `enumtypes.c` files, they are updated but then an escape character gets inserted in front of "#include" .. only in some files ...`xyz.c`
for example , the file `gst-libs\gst\audio\audio-enumtypes.c` is shown like this:

```
...
\#include "audio.h" 
\#include "audio-format.h" 
 ...
```

I even tried directly with git shell .. I got same problem. Not sure what character encoding parameter I should set.

Comment: what is the content of the makefile?